# How would you decrypt an affine cipher with only the ciphertext?

Tags: cryptanalysis, affine-cipher, decryption

If I have only the ciphertext but the alphabet and the value of a and b are all unknown ... how would I go about this? I understand decryption with the key and alphabet, that is fairly easy but if we don't have even one of them what would be my first step?

also, my goal is to have the computer return the plaintext and the alphabet &key. Without me choosing what looks like english or not.

Comment: Try all possible keys and look for meaningful messages?

Comment: How would you get the alphabet from that, though?

Comment: How the ciphertext is given? the values are giving bounds on $a$ and $b$. Than you can consider alphabet.

Comment: @kelalaka How would you look for a and b without having the base alphabet from which the letters were orginally mapped to?

Comment: Ciphertext is being passed into the function

Comment: How the ciphertext is given? What do you mean passed into the function? It should be written somewhere.

Comment: @kelalaka yes, it's python so the function would look like "def crypto(ciphertext): " That's it. I'm just confused how we are supposed to get the keys without any other information